# How can a Java process with -Xmx1024m occupy 3GB resident memory?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

It's a Java web application on Websphere6.1, Solaris 10, JDK 1.5.0_13. We set the maximum heap size to 1024m. jmap shows the heap status is healthy. The heap memory usage is only 57%. No OutOfMemory at all.

But we saw very high RSS (3GB) for this java process from ps. pmap shows a block of 1.9G private memory.

```
3785:   /dmwdkpmmkg/was/610/java/bin/java -server -Dwas.status.socket=65370 -X
 Address  Kbytes     RSS    Anon  Locked Pgsz Mode   Mapped File
...
0020A000    2008    2008    2008       -   8K rwx--    [ heap ]
00400000 1957888 1957888 1957888       -   4M rwx--    [ heap ]
8D076000      40      40      40       -   8K rw--R    [ stack tid=10786 ]
...
```

Is it a C heap memory leak in native code? What approach is recommended to find out the root cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Troubleshooting Memory Leaks](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html) document from Sun may help you with finding the problem why your high RSS, specially in section 3.4.

As you are running Websphere, maybe you can use the *-memorycheck* on your VM. For details see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg000121410cbe-1195c23a635-7ffd_1001.html).

It's not necessarily a leak in native code. If you look [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5004956), on Solaris there might be an issue with files being kept open.

It's just a bunch of links and hints, but maybe helpful to track down your problem.

Comment: They're helpful. While -memorycheck seems only available for IBM JDK? There's no IBM JDK on Solaris, just SUN JDK, right?

Comment: Don't know, I have no experience with Solaris, but likely not ...  Maybe the IBM JDK is coming with Websphere as it's also from IBM. That's what I thought of.

Answer (score 3):

This might happen even when there isn't a native memory leak (like unclosed zip resources).

I ran in to the same problem. This is a known problem with glibc >= 2.10

The cure is to set this env variable

`export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4`

IBM article about setting MALLOC_ARENA_MAX 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/linux_glibc_2_10_rhel_6_malloc_may_show_excessive_virtual_memory_usage?lang=en

Google for MALLOC_ARENA_MAX or search for it on SO to find a lot of references.

You might want to tune also other malloc options to optimize for low fragmentation of allocated memory:

```
# tune glibc memory allocation, optimize for low fragmentation
# limit the number of arenas
# requires glibc >= 2.16 since there was a bug in 
# MALLOC_ARENA_TEST parameter handling that cause MALLOC_ARENA_MAX not to work
export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2
# disable dynamic mmap threshold, see M_MMAP_THRESHOLD in "man mallopt"
export MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_=131072
export MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=131072
export MALLOC_TOP_PAD_=131072
export MALLOC_MMAP_MAX_=65536
```

You can call the native malloc_info function to get information about memory allocations. Here is an example of [using JNA to call the native malloc_info method](https://github.com/lhotari/java-buildpack-diagnostics-app/blob/907d204f21d011f0272c9d47cac9375e5395574b/src/main/groovy/io/github/lhotari/jbpdiagnostics/MallocInfo.java#L20-L28).

Comment: Thanks Lari! Your answer is very convicing. However I don't have the app and solaris env to verify anymore - the origin question was raise 6 years ago :) But thanks for letting me know anyway. The question has been mysterious for me for a while.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35610063 , it has more details about Java native memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

The heap size os the Java heap size, there is still the VM and other libraries which are part of the process.

Try running Hello World with a 1024m heap size and a "for(;;)" in it and see how much it takes up.  That should give you a baseline for overall memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JNI libraries?  I'm not sure how native code allocates RAM but that's where I'd start looking.