# Java memory leak in native internal area

Tags: java, memory-leaks, native

My application (Spring+Tomcat) on openjdk8u66 leaks in internal native memory. Heap GC behaves properly. 
Ex. Xmx=4g. in some time heap still has the same limits, but process memory increased to 6G

With **jcmd** util i've made **summary.diff**  and find out that **Internal** section of result grows +905MB. What is stored there and is there a way to go futher with my investigation?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041117/growing-resident-memory-usage-rss-of-java-process/35610063