# Interpreting jemaloc data possible off-heap leak

Tags: java, jvm

I starting my search 2 weeks ago for an ever growing java memory. I am using the following command to prevent the heap from growing too much and also to do some debugging.

I am running on an Ubuntu 16.04 using oracle java 8, as openjdk 8 did not have the debugging symbols I needed to make jemaloc provide correct data

```
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Xms64m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m -Xss256k
```

As you can see my Xmx is set for 256m. However `top` currently shows my process to be at 1.1G

After using JProfiler and JVisualVm I and many other things I could find on google I have come to the conclusion that this must be an off-heap problem.

After much searching I came across `jemaloc` and the articles I read about it seemed promising. But I am having some problems now interpreting this data. And finding out how to pin point the source of my problem.

[**top memory usage**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayj1j.png)

[**jemaloc graph**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14ft4.gif)

**Native Memory Tracking Data**

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1678MB, committed=498MB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=256MB, committed=256MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=256MB, committed=256MB)

-                     Class (reserved=1103MB, committed=89MB)
                            (classes #14604)
                            (malloc=3MB #32346)
                            (mmap: reserved=1100MB, committed=85MB)

-                    Thread (reserved=26MB, committed=26MB)
                            (thread #53)
                            (stack: reserved=26MB, committed=26MB)

-                      Code (reserved=261MB, committed=96MB)
                            (malloc=17MB #17740)
                            (mmap: reserved=244MB, committed=79MB)

-                        GC (reserved=1MB, committed=1MB)
                            (mmap: reserved=1MB, committed=1MB)

-                  Internal (reserved=6MB, committed=6MB)
                            (malloc=6MB #48332)

-                    Symbol (reserved=19MB, committed=19MB)
                            (malloc=16MB #168491)
                            (arena=4MB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=5MB, committed=5MB)
                            (tracking overhead=4MB)
```

Answer (score 42):

#### Check process memory map

Native Memory Tracking accounts only structures of Java Virtual Machine, but it does not count memory-mapped files nor native memory allocated by shared libraries (including the native code of Java Class Library). Furthermore, NMT does not track any internal fragmentation of `malloc` - standard libc allocator.

First, to analyze off-heap usage of a Java process, look at its full memory map:

```
pmap -X <pid>
```

This will shed light on whether the memory is used by mapped files or by anonymous regions.

#### Change standard allocator

If you see a number of anonymous regions mutiple to 64 MB, this could be a sign of malloc arenas. Libc malloc is known to have issues with [excessive virtual memory usage](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11261) on some systems. Using [`jemalloc`](http://jemalloc.net/) or [`tcmalloc`](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) as a drop-in replacement (even without profiling feature) may become a solution in this case.

#### Profile native allocations

Unfortunately, jemalloc profiler knows nothing about Java; the graph breaks at the last native function, so the output may look confusing. In your case jemalloc suggests the problem may be related to class loading and `System.loadLibrary`, but it's hard to tell for sure without a full picture.

[Async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) allows to trace native allocations in Java context. Run

```
./profiler.sh -d <duration> -e malloc -f malloc.svg <pid>
```

This will produce a [Flame Graph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) of `malloc` calls, e.g.:

[image: Malloc Flame Graph]

This is just an example demonstrating how `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` can be a source of native memory allocations. Your case will be different, of course.

**Note** that `malloc` calls themselves do not mean a memory leak. E.g. memory could be allocated and then released shortly afterwards. The graph is just a hint where to look at.

In order to find places where RSS increases, you may want to trace `mprotect` or `mmap` calls. This can be done with async-profiler in a similar way:

```
./profiler.sh -d <duration> -e mprotect -f mprotect.svg <pid>
./profiler.sh -d <duration> -e mmap -f mmap.svg <pid>
```

#### Pay attention to agent libraries

I've noticed `cbClassPrepare` and `classTrack_processUnloads` functions in your jemalloc graph. This means you are using `jdwp` debugging agent. It can be definitely a reason for excessive memory allocation - I used to see memory leaks in `jdwp` before. Any other agent library enabled through `-agentlib`, `-agentpath` or `-javaagent` options is also a suspect, since their native memory usage is not tracked by JVM.

Comment: `mprotect` and `mmap` produce .jfr with no memory info, only CPU profiling. Is it expected ? @apangin

Comment: @expert When you choose `-e mprotect` or `-e mmap`, you will profile calls of these functions *instead of* CPU sampling. Allocation profiling is irrelevant here. So yes, this is expected.