# Java heap profiling crashes with SIGABRT

Tags: java, jvm, profiling, heap-memory

I'm trying to profile native memory allocated by C-written methods and plugged to `JVM` through `JNI`. I installed

```
$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.13.0
```

And tried to run JVM with the following options:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --massif-out-file=/tmp/massif-j.out java 
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions //...
```

The thing is it crashes with core dump created

```
  0x00000000080e4196: fxrstor64 (%rsp)
  0x00000000080e419b: add     $0x200,%rsp
  0x00000000080e41a2: mov     (%rsp),%r15
  0x00000000080e41a6: mov     0x8(%rsp),%r14
  0x00000000080e41ab: mov     0x10(%rsp),%r13
  0x00000000080e41b0: mov     0x18(%rsp),%r12
  0x00000000080e41b5: mov     0x20(%rsp),%r11
  0x00000000080e41ba: mov     0x28(%rsp),%r10
  0x00000000080e41bf: mov     0x30(%rsp),%r9
  0x00000000080e41c4: mov     0x38(%rsp),%r8
  0x00000000080e41c9: mov     0x40(%rsp),%rdi
  0x00000000080e41ce: mov     0x48(%rsp),%rsi
  0x00000000080e41d3: mov     0x50(%rsp),%rbp
  0x00000000080e41d8: mov     0x60(%rsp),%rbx
  0x00000000080e41dd: mov     0x68(%rsp),%rdx
  0x00000000080e41e2: mov     0x70(%rsp),%rcx
  0x00000000080e41e7: mov     0x78(%rsp),%rax
  0x00000000080e41ec: add     $0x80,%rsp
  0x00000000080e41f3: add     $0x8,%rsp
  0x00000000080e41f7: Fatal error: Disassembling failed with error code: 15#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (sharedRuntime.cpp:834), pid=12441, tid=0x0000000021385700
#  fatal error: exception happened outside interpreter, nmethods and vtable stubs at pc 0x00000000080e4147
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /var/log/prj/core or core.12441
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /var/log/prj/hs_err_pid12441.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
==12441==
==12441== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT): dumping core
==12441==    at 0x54AAE97: raise (raise.c:51)
==12441==    by 0x54AC800: abort (abort.c:79)
==12441==    by 0x658B3C4: ??? (in /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-8-amd64/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
==12441==    by 0x672F5B2: ??? (in /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-8-amd64/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
==12441==    by 0x615EE98: ??? (in /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-8-amd64/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
==12441==    by 0x662A099: ??? (in /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-8-amd64/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
==12441==    by 0x6591A49: JVM_handle_linux_signal (in /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-8-amd64/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
==12441==    by 0x6587652: ??? (in /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-8-amd64/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)
==12441==    by 0x4E4588F: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so)
==12441==    by 0x80E4146: ???
==12441==    by 0x107: ???
==12441==    by 0x84CBC43: ???
==12441==    by 0x10001BD37: ???
==12441==    by 0xFDC7103F: ???
==12441==    by 0xA3FFFFFFFF: ???
==12441==    by 0xFF9275A7: ???
==12441==
```

Can anyone give an idea of what could go wrong? Is that because of `Fatal error: Disassembling failed with error code: 15#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind (and Valgrind-based tools) [does not work well](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.java) with self-modifying code. However, HotSpot JVM heavily relies on dynamic code generation, including overwriting and patching the previously generated instructions. This holds even when JIT compiler is disabled, because HotSpot also uses dynamic code generation for interpreter and runtime stubs.

For native memory allocation profiling you may also use [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) or [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler). The latter has the advatange of integration with Java runtime, i.e. it can show mixed stack traces with both native and Java frames. Furthermore, both tools have rather small performance overhead unlike Valgrind which virtualizes the running program.

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624438/3448419) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598622/3448419) answers.

Comment: I also tried to compile and link the library with `-fsanitize=address`, but unfortunately it could not catch the simple `malloc(sizeof(char));` call from the `JNI` method. Is there some troubles when using address sanitizer when running under JVM?

Comment: @St.Antario No, JVM should not affect `-fsanitize=address`