# Spring boot application not using jemalloc

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, jvm, jemalloc

I am trying to find out a memory leak issue. I am following [this](https://gdstechnology.blog.gov.uk/2015/12/11/using-jemalloc-to-get-to-the-bottom-of-a-memory-leak/) article and trying to use jemalloc

The steps followed are:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so
export MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:30,lg_prof_sample:17
sudo java -jar application.jar
```

However there is no .heap file created. I cannot find libjemalloc.so in pmap -x  result. How can I ensure that the jvm is using jemalloc? Server is an ubuntu server and the application is using spring boot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `sudo`, Java gets root environment which does not have your previously exported `LD_PRELOAD` and `MALLOC_CONF`.

Try

```
sudo LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so \
     MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:30,lg_prof_sample:17 \
     java -jar application.jar
```

BTW, `jemalloc` is not always useful for *profiling* Java applications, since it cannot show Java stacks (but it is useful for *preventing* memory leaks caused by the standard allocator).

Try async-profiler as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598622/3448419).

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624438/3448419) about Java native memory consumption.