# Unable to interpret jeprof result

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, jvm, jemalloc

After setting up jemalloc and jeprof using configuration in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086528/spring-boot-application-not-using-jemalloc) I was able to generate a profiling data.

Then using jeprof I was able to generate the report

```
jeprof --show_bytes --gif /usr/bin/java jeprof.<pid>.*.heap > /tmp/new.gif
```

However I am not able to interpret what is going on. Seems like SUNWprivate_1.1 is doing something but I don't understand what.

Also, I found `JVM_FindSignal` means debug symbols are not found by the profiler. So, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250864/jvm-findsignal-function-continuously-allocates-native-memory) I have run

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-dbg
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything in the output.

Below is the result of jeprof command.

[image]

How do I interpret this result?

Comment: The results are meaningless, because JVM symbols are still not loaded. "SUNWprivate_1.1" cannot do anything - it is just a random version symbol. Make sure you install the right debuginfo package with the same version as JDK. After that rerun Java process from the beginning.