# JVM memory leak diagnosis (jemalloc)

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, jemalloc

A piece of software from a vendor eats an unholy amount of memory over time.
This is a Java application and I've inspected heap and metaspace inside the JRE, everything ok there (uses < 1G RAM). The issue rather seems to be some native memory allocation within the code (which I don't have). So I've used jemalloc to profile and the following is the result.

Is it safe to say that I should ask the vendor to fix their code or what could be the issue here? How can the output of jemalloc be interpreted?

[image]

Comment: The picture is unreadable. Please post the full size image. Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576163/interpreting-jemaloc-data-possible-off-heap-leak) and [this presentation](https://vimeo.com/364039638).

Comment: @apangin I've replaced the image.

Comment: Concerning the memory map (mentioned in one of the questions referred to), all the memory seems to get used up in [heap] or [anon] regions when looking at pmap (this seems to be different depending on which allocator is used, malloc or jemalloc, but it's always [heap] or [anon]...)