# JVM + LEAK + JEMALLOC = Unsafe_AllocateMemory

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, jemalloc

It is being a lot of hour re-searching and try find wth is calling a unsafe.allocateMemory and no success at all. Kind of disappointed :-(
Im not a expert or profile or with jemalloc but here is what I did so far and hopefully someone can see/find what I could not...

- Heap and non-Heap memory are all good...I used yourkit.
- General memory on the box increase crazily until 100% and the jvm crash.
- Using Jemalloc and let the app run for a lot of time I was able to get some JEPROF files and converted some of them into PDF to see the memo/function stack calls:
  [image]

I see that something is calling the ***unsafe.allocateMemory*** and not calling the ***unsafe.freeMemory*** after done, so it will eat all my memory.
I did a thread dump from the application ([link to the txt with the thread dump](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19T7Ks3ja95OBwXyGfIULf73tzlTV747k?usp=sharing)) but unfortunately I was not able to find anything related to the ***unsafe.allocateMemory***. Can anyone see something that I was not able to see or helping me by giving me any clue or pointing me in the right direction ?
Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler). It can show you complete Java stack traces of all callers of `Unsafe_AllocateMemory0`.

Example:

```
./profiler.sh -e Unsafe_AllocateMemory0 -f alloc.html <pid>
```

The output file `alloc.html` will be a flame graph of all `Unsafe_AllocateMemory0` calls:

[image: alloc.html]

For more information about finding native memory leaks in Java, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576163/interpreting-jemaloc-data-possible-off-heap-leak) and [this discussion](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/discussions/491).

Comment: I will try it... thks a lot for the help and attention...