# java on kubernetes - container_memory_working_set_bytes keeps increasing

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, memory-leaks, java-11, glibc

What do we know?

1. openjdk 11 + Jenkins (2.303.3) on openshift 4, 24/7 running and executing jobs, with `-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M` and `xmx=4g`
2. based on [Growing resident memory usage (RSS) of Java Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041117/growing-resident-memory-usage-rss-of-java-process), we use `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4` which made top showing the same the `committed` in java native memory tracking
3. No other processes in the container / pod
4. Although we use groovy grapes a LOT (and fixed mem release bugs) and also quite a bit of zip files (that we generate and stash) `lsof` file handles are stable
5. kubernetes `container_memory_working_set_bytes` increases while `container_memory_rss` is stable
6. fs/memory.stat's `total_rss` keeps stable, so does top and everything that "jvm native memory tracking" records - hence we believe there are no heap or classloader etc leaks (we fixed them one by one :))

What we do NOT know and dont' understand:

1. After 3 days, top reports (inline with native memory tracking and `container_memory_rss`) ~2g, while `container_memory_working_set_bytes` - reports ~3g (and the latter is growing since the start of the container)
2. a graph showing this difference (_rss vs _set_bytes) is at https://github.com/opendevstack/ods-jenkins-shared-library/issues/857#issuecomment-1471786489
3. memory.stat tracking over more than a day shows increased `mapped_file` and `active_file` over time

Anyone ideas how to debug this, or diagnose what's going wr(on)g? At some point (kubernetes memory limit = 4g) the oom pod killer will come along

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem? We have encountered the almost same situation.

Comment: we have solved it - and it was because of a mem leak in jenkins - and we hacked our shared library to clean it up (https://github.com/opendevstack/ods-jenkins-shared-library/pull/980/files) and https://github.com/opendevstack/ods-core/pull/1217/files